# Pumping lemma for regular languages vs. Pumping lemma for context-free languages

Tags: pumping-lemma

How can I prove the next claim:

If a language $L$ meets the pumping lemma for regular languages then $L$ meets the pumping lemma for context-free languages?

(Without any pre-condition about the regularity of $L$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pumping lemma of context-free languages means finding $x,y,z,v,u$ such $w=xvyuz, |vu|>0,|vxu|\le p$, and for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $xv^nyu^nz$

The regular pumping lemma means finding only $v,y,u$ where $w=abc,|b|>0,|ab|\le p$ and $ab^nc\in L$. ("a","b","c" here are representing sub-words of w)

So, simply take $x=a,v=b,y=c,u=\epsilon,z=\epsilon$